# What is appropriate http status code for database operation failure?

Tags: php, rest, http, laravel, http-status-codes

I am working with a laravel project and willing to implement the best practice of web development. For some ajax requests, I am returning json response. For example, when I delete a record, I return `204` http status code

```
return response()->json([], 204);
```

But when I delete a record, I want to make sure the delete operation was successful. If the operation is not successful, I want to return a different status code and I want to know which status code is most appropriate for this case?

My code example is

```
if($department->delete()){

    //delete success and return 204
    return response()->json([], 204);

}else{
    //delete is not success, what is appropriate status code for this?
    return response()->json([], 500);
}
```

Comment: In my personal opinion, 500 is just fine there.

Comment: 500 is "Internal Server Error". When the server is unable to delete something on the database, that sounds like an internal server error, does it not?

Comment: @sjagr thats what I wanted to be sure.. to know the industry best practice.

Comment: In general I don't think the user should care what _exactly_ went wrong. The website should just say there was a problem and try again/later/whatever.